Crack in concrete leaks water and has worms inside
my wife and I purchased a ~15-year-old home in the midwest about 1.5 years ago, and this crack in the concrete is in the inside of our garden garage. It's becoming increasingly discolored, the last heavy rain we received resulted in a very minor leak, and it now has a bunch of little worms in it (see pic)!
It seems like this is something that needs addressed - does anyone have any effective ideas, and should I be concerned about any other implications that may arise from the leaking AND worm combo?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Please confirm whether this is a picture of a wall or a floor.

Sorry for not being clear in my original post - this is a picture of the wall. The black at the very bottom of the picture is the floor (rubber matting)
